# Can I keep one foreground service running to prevent other background service being killed in android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

From google doc it said:

> The system distinguishes between foreground and background apps. An app is
> considered to be in the foreground if any of the following is true:
>
> 1.It has a visible activity, whether the activity is started or paused.
>
> 2.It has a foreground service.

And it also said:

> While an app is in the foreground, it can create and run both foreground and background services freely

So, say I start a foreground service when user started the app (it can always has the notification displayed and this is fun) and keep it running until user force quit the app. Then will my intentservice that try to fetch some data in the background get killed if the app entered background?

PS. the foreground service will not doing anything, it's just there to prevent other background service getting killed. (cause call startservice() will get IllegalArgumentException in the background after API 26)

Will this work?

Comment: This seems like the wrong way to approach the problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I was trying to prevent the background service (intentservice) getting killed after API 26. I think I'd better to convert intentservice to jobIntentservice. But, by reading through the doc, it seems to be this is a HACK way.

Comment: The foreground service will help keep your app alive for as long as possible, whether your other service is doing work or not.